# Image formation by convex lens

Tags: optics, refraction, lenses

If an image of an object formed by convex lens is simply meeting of the rays of the object due to refraction,then why do we require a screen to reflect these refracted rays?If we observe the image formation from the side the image is forming,shouldn't the rays of the image reach our eyes without a screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, you see the image in the same place when the screen is removed (You don't need the magnifying glass).

> [image]
>   [Fun Science Gallery](http://www.funsci.com/fun3_en/lens/lens.htm)

Comment: What if your eye is in the imaging plane? This is not completely accurate! Specially considering the question. He asked if the image would form in your eyes, from what I gather the confusion is that our eyes are like the screen. And also why is it that we need the screen. You answered none of those questions, you simply said "Your eyes see things in an imaging setup, heres an example of an experiment that you can do by yourself". While he could do it, it still did not answer why is it like that. Just explain then why does he need to be far away from the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Your form an image of your object on the screen. Your eyes, to see things need to do the same. Do not forget that when using the screen there are no more lenses. But if you look into the rays coming from the lens, you now include also your own eyeball lenses into the optical beam path. Your retina, at the back of your eyes **IS** the screen.

Putting it in different words, when you look at an object, your eyes and retina are doing exactly the same as the lens and screen you proposed. In a way, you are seeing how your eye works!! Except that instead of having a screen you have cells which are sensitive to light!